# Spring Boot not able to parse model data in JSP

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp, tomcat, jstl

I have a simple `JSP` `webapp` that should display `Hello World` on the page but for some reason the `model` data is not getting parsed.

**Actual Output on browser:** `Hello ${name}!`

**Expected Output on browser:** `Hello World!`

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.howtodoinjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-demo</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-demo Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Tomcat Embed -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- To compile JSP files -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**IndexController.java**

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @GetMapping({"/", "/hello"})
    public String hello(Model model, @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

**MvcConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        registry.viewResolver(resolver);
    }

}
```

**SpringBootWebApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootWebApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

**WEB-INF/view/hello.jsp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello ${name}!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2 class="hello-title">Hello ${name}!</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I didn't check your config but as far as I remember you use a wrong syntax
<h2>Hello <c:out value="${name}"></c:out></h2>

Comment: Added `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` on top of the page and changed to `<c:out value="${name}"></c:out>` but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by changing package type from `war` to `jar` and some code changes. See below.

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.howtodoinjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-boot-demo Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**SpringBootWebApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**hello.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Hello ${name}!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2 class="hello-title">Hello ${name}!</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

**MvcConfiguration.java (DELETED)**

**Actual output in browser now:** `Hello World!`